# Oracle replace comma, but only if no space after

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm finding examples for other languages, but I really don't understand regular expressions, so it's hard to convert to Oracle syntax.

I think I want to use REGEXP_REPLACE, and I want to replace a comma with a dash, but only if there is no space after the comma.  So, for example:

> TABLE TREE,TREE SPECIES, MAPLE

would replace the first comma, but not the second:

> TABLE TREE-TREE SPECIES, MAPLE

I can do a simple REGEXP_REPLACE, but only the opposite of what I want:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FieldToChange, ', ', '-')
```

That's the same as a straight REPLACE, which I do understand.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FieldToChange, ',[^ ]', '-')
```

That grabs only the comma that doesn't have a space after, but it is taking the next character too, resulting in:

> TABLE TREE-REE SPECIES, MAPLE

I'm reading the Oracle docs, but like many docs, you need to understand quite a bit before the docs make any sense.  Therefore, I'd really like an explanation, rather than a simple answer.  (The other answers I've found, for other languages, are just giving the answer, which isn't helping me convert this to Oracle.)

Answer (score 3):

Your regex in `REGEXP_REPLACE(FieldToChange, ',[^ ]', '-')` matches a comma with `,` and any char other than a space with the `[^ ]` negated bracket expression. The matched text is replaced with `-`, your replacement pattern.

In regex, a position not followed with some other pattern is usually matched (or "asserted") with the help of a negative lookahead (like `(?! )`). However, Oracle regex engine is POSIX based, and does not support lookarounds.

You may rely on the *capturing* mechanism here:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FieldToChange, ',([^ ])', '-\1')
```

Now, `([^ ])` *captures* any char but space into Group 1 and you may reference the value in the group with a `\1` in the replacement pattern. `\1` is a numeric replacement backreference. You may have up to 9 groups in your pattern, POSIX `\1`-like pbackreferences do not allow more (from `1` to `9`).

If you want to also match a comma at the end of the string, you need to use an alternation in the group:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FieldToChange, ',([^ ]|$)', '-\1')
```

The `([^ ]|$)` capturing group matches either any char but space or end of string. You can't use `[^ $]` because `$` loses its end-of-string anchor meaning inside the bracket expression and `[^ $]` matches any char but space and dollar symbol.

Comment: Thank you.  That is starting to make a bit of sense.  An explanation helps me learn, rather than just make code.  Also, it works, which I also wanted.